# Посоветуйте PHP-библиотеку проверки пользовательского HTML на безопасность

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте,

Посоветуйте пожалуйста библиотеку или скрипт, который проверит `html`-страницу загруженную пользователем на предмет небезопасного содержимого.

Интересует проверка HTML и CSS.

**Обновление**

Допустим встроенные скрипты на `php`, которые при определенных условиях могут выполняться на стороне сервера при генерации страницы. Любые другие теги которые не сломают страницу во время генерации на сервере и просмотре на клиенте, как например `ifame` позволит получить данные о пользователях открывших страницу, а так же . К небезопасному CSS могу отнести стили, имеющие в своем описании `url(http://somesite.com/hack.css)` который так же позволит вытащить данные о клиенте. Насколько я знаю, это называется HTML-инъекция

Comment: Что подразумевается под небезопасным содержимым? Под небезопасным CSS?

Comment: Не знаю куда писать модераторам на этой платформе, поэтому напишу здесь. Это не вопрос-опросник. Я не спрашивал "какая на Ваш взгляд библиотека лучше", а хотел узнать, может кто из сообщества уже задавался этим вопросом и что-то для этого использовал. Спустя 4 часа в сети нашел несколько более-менее актуальных библиотек: HTML Purifier, MarkHtml и Jevix. Находил и другие проекты, но они более мертвые чем живые

Comment: Для защиты от XSS используйте белый список вместо чёрного. Так надёжнее. Пользователь отправляет html серверу. Сервер применяет http://php.net/manual/ru/book.tidy.php, получает xml. Парсит xml, тег за тегом, аттрибут за аттрибутом. При парсинге удаляется всё, чего нет в белом списке.

Comment: @atom-22: к сожалению или к счастью, широкие вопросы вроде "порекомендуйте на ваш субъективный взгляд лучшее решение для большой проблемы" не входят в тематику сайта. Формат вопросов и ответов предполагает, что может быть дан объективно верный ответ, который можно воспроизвести и т.п. (как в науке с гипотезами). Такие вопросы, как этот, важны — но для них больше подходит формат блога, обзорной статьи и т.п.

Comment: А что касается «вопроса-опросника», это просто формулировка не очень удачная. Разумеется, никто не имел в виду, что вы соцопрос устраиваете. Просто все используют эту причину для закрытия вопросов, на которые возможно отвечать только субъективными мнениями. Вообще-то, под это другая формулировка есть, специальная, но используют эту.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос был задан с намеком на то, что вы гоняетесь за неуловимым *чем-то*. Каким образом можно узнать, есть ли в css ссылки на динамические обработчики? Каким образом разработчики абстрактной библиотеки могут узнать, что именно вы ищете в документе? Каким образом можно отследить XSS без помощи ИИ? Этому всему можно задать формальные критерии? Если вам нужно отфильтровать все небезопасное, то просто режьте все потенциально проблемные теги (даже изображения, ага), если вам нужен ответ, содержит ли страница нечто небезопасное, то вам его никто не даст без, опять же, искусственного интеллекта.